# SQL GROUP BY AND VALUE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table

```
AvailbilityDate |   Resort    |  AccomName  |  Price    |  Min Occupancy
24 June 2012    |    Resort1  |    Accom1   |     999   |    8
24 June 2012    |    Resort1  |    Accom2   |     888   |    6
24 June 2012    |    Resort2  |    Accom1a  |     243   |    10
24 June 2012    |    Resort2  |    Accom2a  |     563   |    7
```

What I currently have is

```
SELECT AvailbilityDate, Resort, MIN(Price) AS Lowest 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY AvailbilityDate, Resort
```

I want to be able to get the `AccomName` and the `Min Occupancy`

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which flavour of sql server are you using?  Is it ProgresSQL, mySQL, Microsoft SQL (if so which version?)

Comment: MS SQL I may need to also make it clearer that the group by works but I want to be able to get the Chalet Name and Min Occ but I dont want to include it in the group by clause

Comment: i want 
AvailabilityDate, Resort, (Cheapest Price), AccomName Min Occupancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard ANSI SQL, the solution would be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT AvailbilityDate, 
          resort,
          accomName,
          price,
          min_occupancy,
          min(price) over (partition by AvailbilityDate, Resort) as min_price
   FROM deals_panel_view
) t
WHERE min_price = price;
```

Should work on PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Terradata

Comment: @richard. No `t` is the alias for the inner select. Sorry I forgot the FROM part there ;)

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT real_dep_date, 
          resort_name,
          real_price,
        std_occ,
          min(real_price) over (partition by real_dep_date,resort_name) as min_price
) deals_panel_view
WHERE min_price = real_price;

Comment: @richard: see my edit. the table name needs to go into the inner select

Comment: @richard: I have no idea why. I don't use management studio. Maybe the alternative posted by Bob Vale does not make it crash

Comment: Problem with SQL management Studio  Thanks Horse i have a learnt a litle more and Bob I shall look to use the with clause

Answer (score 1):

Using a common table expression and Ranking functions you can do this

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY AvailabilityDate,Resort ORDER BY price) as row,
  AvailbilityDate,
  Resort,
  AccomName,
  Price,
  [Min Occupancy] 
FROM mytable  
)
SELECT AvailbilityDate,Resort,Price,AccomName,[Min Occupancy] from cte where row=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AvailbilityDate, Resort, AccomName, "Min Occupancy", MIN(Price) AS Lowest 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY AvailbilityDate, Resort
```

Comment: Won't work, because you need to include the "min occupancy" and accomName in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: MS SQL will complain that "Min Occupancy" and AccomName are not in the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways.

1) Ranking - per a_horse_with_no_name's solution

2) Group by and Cross Apply. Essentially plug the columns you want to group up in the first subquery and then all other columns go into the second subquery. Use an Order By in the second subquery to deal with any column you want to apply MIN (or MAX) to.

```
SELECT a.AvailbilityDate, 
       a.resort,
       b.AccomName,
       b.min_occupancy,
       b.Lowest
FROM 
(
 SELECT t1.AvailbilityDate, t1.resort
  FROM myTable t1
  GROUP BY t1.AvailbilityDate, t1.resort
 ) a
CROSS APPLY
( 
  SELECT TOP 1 t2.AccomName, t2.min_occupancy, t2.price as Lowest
      FROM mytable t2
         WHERE t2.AvailbilityDate = a.AvailbilityDate
          AND t2.resort = a.resort
          ORDER BY t2.price ASC
) b
```

3) Use subqueries in select statement (not very elegant but works) with Group By. This is assuming that there is only one accomName with the given minimum price for each combination of AvailbilityDate and resort.

```
SELECT a.AvailbilityDate, 
       a.resort,
       (SELECT accomName FROM myTable t1
         WHERE t1.AvailbilityDate = a.AvailbilityDate
          AND t1.resort = a.resort
          AND t1.price = MIN(a.price)
       ) as accomName,
       (SELECT min_occupancy FROM myTable t1
         WHERE t1.AvailbilityDate = a.AvailbilityDate
          AND t1.resort = a.resort
          AND t1.price = MIN(a.price)
       ) as min_occupancy,
       MIN(a.price) as Lowest
  FROM myTable a
  GROUP BY a.AvailbilityDate, a.resort
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT AccomName, MIN([Min Occupancy]) AS Lowest FROM mytable GROUP BY AccomName

That would give you ONLY the desired Infos. If you want to have the desired fields in ADDITION to what you have already, it would be like:

SELECT AvailbilityDate, AccomName, Resort, MIN(Price) AS Lowest, Min([Min Occupancy]) As LowestMinOcc FROM mytable GROUP BY AvailbilityDate , AccomName , Resort

Comment: That will give muiltiple lines per resort because the accomnames are different